# compute this integral from zero to infinity

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

compute the following integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x}dx=?$$ 
where, a & b are both negative real numbers

i tried this way:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x}dx$$,

$$=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}}{x}dx-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{bx}}{x}dx$$,

then using product rule for first integral

$$\int\frac{e^{ax}}{x}dx=\frac{1}{x}(ae^{ax})-\int \frac{-1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{x}(ae^{ax})$$,

$$=\frac{ae^{ax}}{x}+a\int \frac{e^{ax}}{x^3} dx$$,

it is getting more complex i don't know how to proceed, my book gives answer $\ln|b/a|$ my teacher asked me to use Laplace transform but do'nt know how to apply, please tell me some other easy method to compute this integral. when i tried this way

by Frullani's integral

$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x}dx=\left(f(0)-f(\infty)\right)\ln\frac{b}{a}$

$=\left(e^{0}-e^{(\infty)}\right)\ln\frac{b}{a}\to -\infty$

still i am not getting a finite value so where am i wrong?

thank you in advance!

Comment: splitting is not going to work here. I don't know what integration tools you have available, but one thing that comes to mind is using the Laplace Transform.(Did not downvote)

Comment: please help me solve it byusing laplace transform

Comment: Are you assuming $a$ and $b$ are both negative?

Comment: @jeanneclement How much have you studied the Laplace transform?

Comment: for positive $a,b$ the integral is superdivergent

Comment: @jeanneclement, you need to assume they are *negative*, not positive.

Comment: sorry, yes both a & b are negative

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html

Comment: Hint: Consider 

$$
(\partial_a+\partial_b)I(a,b)=-\int_0^{\infty}(e^{-ax}-e^{-bx})=-\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}
$$

$$
I(a,b)=\log(b/a)+C
$$

Comment: @tired Lovely stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working purely formally, define a function

$$I(r)=\int_0^\infty{1-e^{rx}\over x}dx$$

(with $r\lt0$, in order for the improper integral to converge).  Then

$${dI\over dr}=\int_0^\infty{{d\over dr}(1-e^{rx})\over x}dx=\int_0^\infty{-xe^{rx}\over x}dx=-\int_0^\infty e^{rx}dx={1\over r}$$

This implies

$$\int_0^\infty{e^{ax}-e^{bx}\over x}dx=I(b)-I(a)=\int_a^b{dI\over dr}dr=\int_a^b{dr\over r}=\ln|b/a|$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Double Integral::

$$I = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x}dx = \int^{\infty}_{0}\int^{a}_{b}e^{xt}dtdx = \int^{a}_{b}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{xt}dxdt$$

So $$I = \int^{a}_{b}\left[\frac{e^{xt}}{t}\right]_{0}^{\infty}dt = -\int^{a}_{b}\frac{1}{t}dt = -\left(\ln |x|\right)_{b}^{a}= \ln \left |\frac{b}{a}\right|$$